# TCP: Possible SYN flooding on port 80. Dropping request even though net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies set to zero

Tags: linux, centos

I have a strange issue, `net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies` is set to zero.
but I still have the following warning in my /var/log/messages
`TCP: Possible SYN flooding on port 80. Dropping request.`

```
sysctl -a | grep cooki
net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies = 0
net.ipv4.tcp_cookie_size = 0
=========================================
net.ipv4.tcp_max_syn_backlog=500000
=========================================

iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination   

=========================================
Centos 6.2 64bit
Linux 3.0.0+ #1 SMP Fri Oct 26 07:55:47 EEST 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

/var/log/messges

```
net_ratelimit: 6168 callbacks suppressed
TCP: Possible SYN flooding on port 80. Dropping request.
TCP: Possible SYN flooding on port 80. Dropping request.
TCP: Possible SYN flooding on port 80. Dropping request.
TCP: Possible SYN flooding on port 80. Dropping request.
TCP: Possible SYN flooding on port 80. Dropping request.
TCP: Possible SYN flooding on port 80. Dropping request.
TCP: Possible SYN flooding on port 80. Dropping request.
TCP: Possible SYN flooding on port 80. Dropping request.
TCP: Possible SYN flooding on port 80. Dropping request.
TCP: Possible SYN flooding on port 80. Dropping request.
```

Comment: Can you provide more information from the mangle and nat tables?
iptables -nvL -t nat; iptables -nvL -t mangle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each application passes a backlog parameter when making the listen call to listen on a port. If the application is slow in processing connection requests you can end up with those messages which are a bit misleading. The parameter is like a per port tcp_max_syn_backlog.

Comment: Very misleading, I changed worker_connections to 655350 in nginx and it's gone